# Tire Pressure Sensor Replacement Doesn't Register

Tags: dodge, grand-caravan

A while ago my mechanic had to remove a tire pressure sensor because it was rusted on or something when he was replacing the tires.

So the other day he finally replaced it with a new one.  But now my "Low Tire Pressure" light is still on.  I have driven a few hundred kilometers maybe since then, and it's still on.  How can I fix this?

I have a 2010 Dodge Grand Caravan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all the tire pressures (~36psi) are correct including the spare as it may have a sensor.

The module is supposed to relearn the sensor IDs on it's own, but I've rarely found that to be the case and have to manually add the new sensor ID to the module. Or write the old sensor ID to the new sensor (if the old sensor was readable).

If you need to rewrite the sensor IDs, use a scan tool that can write to the Wireless Control Module (e.g. DRB3 or aftermarket equivalent) or whatever module handles the TPM system.

Comment: I filled up all the tires to 41psi just to be sure.  One of the tires was somewhat low.  As soon as I did that, the warning light went off.  What a concept.